# Spamhaus заблокировал VPS, поменяем MX-запись на другой хостинг - куда пойдут письма?

Tags: dns, vps, email

Вчера Spamhaus заблокировал целую подсеть провайдера Rusonyx, в число заблокированных ip-адресов попал, к сожалению ip-адрес нашей VPS у них.

В итоге вот уже почти сутки не работает почта. Тех. поддержка обещает решить проблему в скором времени, а время идет, наш бизнес терпит убытки.

Для этого случая мы ранее предусмотрели управление зоной нашего домена у netangels.

И вот собственно вопрос: Если мы сейчас поменяем MX-запись для нашего домена, то почта начнет приходить на другой хостинг (так же подготовленный и настроенный почтовый сервер) ? Письма, которые были нам отправлены в момент блокировки ip нашей VPS где-то зависли или всё-таки будут доставлены на другой хостинг (на который мы переключим через MX-запись в настройках DNS домена)?

Comment: Что то я немного не понял. Spamhaus - это блокировщик спама и "заблокировал" - это записал в свои черные списки. В этом случае входящая к вам почта должна продолжать к вам приходить, это же не пров зблочил порт ... У вас возникнут проблемы с исходящей от вас почтой, потому как ее начнут считать спамом. Но причем тут ваш MX который отвечает за входящую, а не исходящую почту ... Да, надо отправлять новую почту с "чистого" ip, но принимать то и на старом можно ...

Comment: "не работает почта" - не отправляется или даже и не принимается? Формулируйте точнее

Comment: и не отправляет и не принимает, получается нам наша тех. поддержка на уши лапшу вешает. так по логике вещей как же Spamhaus может действительно влиять на приём сообщений нами.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы сейчас поменяете MX-запись, то почта приходить начнёт. Но не сразу. И не от всех. От конкретного отправителя почта начнёт приходить только когда он получит новый IP-адрес для MX. А это зависит от TTL зоны. В общем случае можно считать, что подавляющее большинство клиентов обновит зону через удвоенное TTL. То есть если у вас TTL=1d, ждите не менее двух дней. Но есть кривые DNS-кэши и у них время реакции может быть вообще бесконечным (один раз адрес получили и никогда не обновляют). Впрочем, такие сейчас редкость.

Письма, отправленные клиентам, проверяющих отправителя по блэклистам *Spamhaus*, во время действия блокировки с вероятностью близкой к 100% отброшены принимающей стороной и доставлены не будут. Возможен только один вариант - ваш MTA, видя что письмо не проходит, может через некоторое время повторить отправку. На практике если письмо определяется как спам, оно сразу же отбрасывается. Иногда спам валится в отдельный ящик, но случаи его просмотра, особенно в крупных компаниях, крайне редки.

P.S. Всегда удивлялся тем, кто использует почтовые блэклисты "мутных" фирмочек. Контентный анализ работает не хуже. Сам использую байесову фильтрацию и никто не жалуется.

Comment: время обновления TTL в настройках DNS-зоны у нас стоит 15 минут.